# How to add a Year shortcode in wordpress Menu

Tags: menus

```php
function current_year() {
    $year = date('Y');
    return $year;
}

add_shortcode('year', 'current_year');
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is this copyright statement going? In your footer I assume? If so, I'd recommend just adding it to your `footer.php` file rather than adding it to a menu. Or check your theme customization settings to see if it allows you to enter text there.